# Stencil Buffer & Stencil Test

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, stencil-buffer

according to the books that i've read stencil test is achieved by comparing a reference value with that of the stencil buffer corresponding to a pixel, how ever in one of the books it states that:

`A mask is bitwise AND-ed with the value in the stencil planes and with the reference value before the comparison is applied`

here i see a third parameter which is the mask, is this a mask related to the stencil buffer or it is another parameter generated by openGL itself??

can someone explain the comparison process and the `values` that have a role in this process??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glStencilMask (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glStencilMask.xml) is used to enable or disable writing to individual bits in the stencil buffer. To make the number of parameters manageable and accommodate stencil buffers of varying bit-depth, it takes a `GLuint` instead of individual `GLboolean`s like [`glColorMask (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glColorMask.xml) and [`glDepthMask (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glDepthMask.xml).

Typically the stencil buffer is 8-bits wide, though it need not be. The default stencil mask is such that every bit-plane is enabled. In an 8-bit stencil buffer, this means the default mask is 0xff (11111111b). Additionally, stenciling can be done separately for front/back facing polygons in OpenGL 2.0+, so there are technically two stencil masks.

In your question, you are likely referring to [`glStencilFunc (...)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/xhtml/glStencilFunc.xml), which also has a mask. This mask is not associated with the stencil buffer itself, but with the actual stencil test. The principle is the same, however; the above link details how this mask is AND'd together with the ref. value during testing.

Answer (score 1):

A mask is an optional extra that sits between what is rendered and what it sent to be rendered.

Imagine you have a scene being rendered and you suddenly decide that you don't want any red being used by a certain object. You can use the mask to apply a bitwise operation to every pixel that object affects to remove the red values.

- `r:150 b:50 g:47` becomes `r:0 b:50  g:47`
- `r:13 b:255 g:255` becomes `r:0 b:255 g:255`

etc.

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glColorMask.xml should help explain it a bit more.